# how to echo custom-defined message remotely?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two machines, A and B, connected via Ethernet cable, and their connections are established. One of the ROS package implemented at the machine A has custom messages, and I would like it to be read at the machine B by using the command `rostopic echo <topic-name>`.

When I typed the command, I got the following error message.

```
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [<message-name>]. Are your messages built?
```

Does this mean that I have to build the custom message at the machine B as well? If so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286263/how-to-echo-custom-defined-message-remotely?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Does this mean that I have to build the custom message at the machine B as well?

That would be the most straightforward way, yes.

> If so, how?

Exactly the same way as you built the package on machine A:

- create a Catkin workspace
- copy the *sources* of the package that contains your msg definitions to machine B
- `catkin_make`
- `source devel/setup.bash

`rostopic` should now be able to find your message definitions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
Note that a convenient way to share sources of packages between multiple machines would be use a VCS like git, svn or hg.